# Spring yaml property java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, properties, environment-variables

I try to pass Docker env variable in my Spring boot application.yml like this:

```
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          my-saml:
            signing:
              credentials:
                - private-key-location: classpath:HARD_PATH_TO_KEY
                  certificate-location: classpath:HARD_PATH_TO_CERT
            identityprovider:
              verification.credentials:
                - certificate-location: classpath:HARD_PATH_TO_CERT
              entity-id: MY_ID
              singlesignon:
                url: {{saml.ip.singlesignon.url}}
                sign-request: true
```

But when I use env variable to

```
            - private-key-location: {{saml.ip.private.key}}
              certificate-location: {{saml.ip.certif.emp}}
```

and

```
          verification.credentials:
            - certificate-location: {{saml.ip.certif2.emp}}
```

I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.buildFlattenedMap(YamlProcessor.java:309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.lambda$buildFlattenedMap$1(YamlProcessor.java:325)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.buildFlattenedMap(YamlProcessor.java:309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.lambda$buildFlattenedMap$1(YamlProcessor.java:325)
    at java.util.Collections$SingletonMap.forEach(Collections.java:4910)
```

Any idea

Comment: Are you saying it works if you hard-code values but does not when you use environment variables?

Comment: Yes, It works also when I pass environnement variable with singlesignon: url: only, but It doesnt work with the others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the '-' at the beginning of lines

```
          private-key-location: {{saml.ip.private.key}}
          certificate-location: {{saml.ip.certif.emp}}
          ...
          certificate-location: {{saml.ip.certif2.emp}}
```

Comment: It doesn't work if I remove - the certificate url is not regonized by SAML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 separate Strings, or `credentials` is a Map, I think it should be:

```yaml
             credentials:
                 private-key-location: {{saml.ip.private.key}}
                 certificate-location: {{saml.ip.certif.emp}}
```

If you want an array, I think it should be:

```yaml
             credentials:
                 - private-key-location: {{saml.ip.private.key}}
                 - certificate-location: {{saml.ip.certif.emp}}
```

Comment: It doesn't work if I remove - the certificate url is not regonized by SAML.